# Setting up the value of a field in a form taking from a Profile

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard, sfdoctrineguard

I need some help here understanding how this works. See I'm using `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin` and add a Profile table as follow:

```
SfGuardUserProfile:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sf_guard_user_profile
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(8), primary: true }
    user_id: { type: integer(8), primary: false }
    idempresa: { type: integer(4), primary: false }
  relations:
    User:
      local: user_id
      class: sfGuardUser
      type: one
      foreignType: one
      foreignAlias: SfGuardUserProfile
      onDelete: CASCADE
      onUpdate: CASCADE
```

Now I need to setup a field value based on logged in user in `SdrivingEmisorForm`, for that I need to access to `idempresa` on `sf_guard_user_profile` but I don`t know how :-( I tried all this:

```
$user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser();

echo $user->getGuardUser()->getProfile()->getIdempresa();
echo $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getProfile()->getIdempresa();
echo $user->getProfile()->getIdempresa();
```

and none works, which is the right way to access to profile fields based on my schema definition? Can any take a brief and explain a bit how I must understand this in order to no get the same doubt if things changes some day?

**EDIT**
I've found the solution but using `sfContext::getInstance()` which many says is wrong, so in this case what is the right way to do this. Below th code works for me:

```
$user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getSfGuardUserProfile()->getIdempresa();
```

PS: I'm access from `SdrivingEmisorForm` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the foreignAlias as SfGuardUserProfile, so you should use this name for the getter.
In some action:

```
$profile = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getSfGuardUserProfile();
```

In some template:

```
$profile = $sf_user->getGuardUser()->getSfGuardUserProfile();
```

Then:

```
echo $profile->getIdempresa();
```